# A Quote of Ven. Leo Dupont on Never Making Peace with One's Sins

Tags: catholicism, sin, reference-request, saint, repentance

I am trying to find a reference which contains an actual quote from Ven. Leo Dupont, which, as I recollect, can be paraphrased as *"... but I have never made peace with my sins."*

Is anyone familiar with the complete and actual quote, and can tell me where to find it?

Related to this question is [How does the Catholic Church tell us to do reparation for our sins according to Church teachings?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/74067/how-does-the-catholic-church-tell-us-to-do-reparation-for-our-sins-according-to/79902#79902) in which a reference to Ven. Leo Dupont is made.

Answer (score 1):

The quote is from [Ven. Louis da Ponte](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luis_de_la_Puente) (not [Ven. Leo Dupont](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leo_Dupont)):

> **"I have committed many faults, but I have never made peace with my faults. Many make peace with their defects, and this shall cause their ruin."**

A reference to this is made by St. Alphonsus Liguori in his book *Dignity and Duties of the Priest* [page 103](https://archive.org/details/alphonsusworks12liguuoft/page/102/mode/1up):

> The Venerable Louis da Ponte used to say: "I have committed many faults, but I have never made peace with my faults. Many make peace with their defects, and this shall cause their ruin."

Comment: There's a huge doctrinal difference in this quotation if one changes "faults" to "sins".